# Why does pytest not run conftest.py functions that are passed as parameters to a test function?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm writing pytests that (for the sake of example), write values to an array.

I need that array to be reset to default values every time I start a test again, so I have a conftest.py function that I supposed to run every time I call a test, that resets the values in the array to their defaults.

I am passing in the index and values to the function that writes the array values as pytest parameters (here is the example test_array.py file):

```
import pytest

def write_array_index(array, idx, val):
    array[idx] = val
    return 0

@pytest.mark.parametrize("idx", [0, 1])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("val", [255])
def test_array_write(our_array, reset_vals, idx, val):
    write_array_index(our_array, idx, val)
    print(our_array)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("idx", [0, 1])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("val", [123])
def test_array_write_again(our_array, reset_vals, idx, val):
    write_array_index(our_array, idx, val)
    print(our_array)
```

Whenever I start a new test, the array is supposed to get reset using the conftest.py (note that the test functions have `reset_vals` as a parameter to them:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def our_array(request):
    array = [0, 0]
    return array

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def reset_vals(our_array):
    our_array = [1, 1]
```

However, whenever a test is repeatedly called as a result of the parameters being used, our_array is not called. See output below:

```
$ pytest -rP ./test_array.py
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.4, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
collected 4 items                                                              

test_array.py ....                                                       [100%]

==================================== PASSES ====================================
___________________________ test_array_write[255-0] ____________________________
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
[255, 0]
___________________________ test_array_write[255-1] ____________________________
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
[255, 255]
________________________ test_array_write_again[123-0] _________________________
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
[123, 255]
________________________ test_array_write_again[123-1] _________________________
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
[123, 123]
============================== 4 passed in 0.01s ===============================
```

Why?
Is there some way to prevent pytest doing this (and actually run the conftest.py functions that are labelled as `scope='function'` every time that function runs?

Might as well just put the reset function as a normal python function at the top of the test_array.py file and call it manually as the first line in every test function..

Thanks

P.S. Note that I cannot re-create the array from scratch every time I call the function. I.e. set `our_array()` to have scope `@pytest.fixture(scope='session')`. This would solve the problem in a simple example, but in the actual use case it is a long process to set up the test object and there are many tests.

Comment: Have you considered (also) using `unittest`? Its `unittest.TestCase` have setup and teardown methods that are intended for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Wasn't my choice to use pytest and I can't change it, unfortunately. Thanks though

Comment: There's no need to change it - you can simply include `unittest`, they work together

Comment: Ah right, thanks I'll have a look then

Comment: You are not resetting the list in `reset_array`. To _change_ a list instead of reassigning it you have to write `our_array[:] = [1, 1]`. Also I would not mix `pytest` with `unittest` functionality in new tests, there is no need for this. This is meant for upwards compatibility only.

Comment: As an aside - you could either return the list (`our_array`) from your `reset_array` fixture, so you don't need to add the `our_array` fixture to your tests, or you could set it to `autouse=True`, so it will be called automatically.

Comment: Another note: try to use the standard terminology to avoid confusion, e.g. `fixture`, not `function` (you cannot call a ficture directly like a function), and better name your lists `list` instead of `array` (which is something else in Python).